# "Call requires permissions that may be rejected by user" requires implementation except in imported code

Tags: android, android-permissions, locationmanager

I am programming in Android using LocationManager. I build a simple app that just shows the current location. And I got the error of the title.

Now, this question has been posted several times but before someone tags this question as a duplicate, please acknowledge that it is not, and I will explain why

All other questions explain that this problems is because Android 6 now require to explicitly ask for permission at runtime. So I did that and I solved my problem. (well it is almost working)

Why did I take so much time in solving it? It is because I had another version of the program that run without problems *without any explicit request for permissions*

This other version was yes, built before Android 23 I think, it was built in eclipse and I just downloaded the project, and imported it to Android Studio changing the platform in build.gradle to make it run successfully. So I thought that it was converted to Android 6 already.

So the imported program worked without any explicit request for permission but my program had to have this. *Why is this so?*

My second question is, the editor did clearly underlined in red the LocationManager functions declaring that they need explicit request for permission. (In the other imported program this did not happen) However even after I did ask for permission, and even after the program run successfully, it still underlined them in red. *Why?*

Comment: Well, you wanted Android 6+. And here you are, with new problems. This time it's called `runtime permissions`.

Comment: Yes, but my question goes more for: If an application was built for a lesser version and then imported to A Studio and the gradle modified to API level 23, it still is not Android 6? once programmed for a lesser version always that version (but will run on a Android 6 machine no problem)?

Comment: The "conversion" only updates the targetSdkVersion. It doesn't modify your code by adding the necessary modifications.